# How to chat with users who have low rep and are unable to join in chat

Tags: discussion, support

I was commenting on a user questions, and Stack Overflow suggested that I should continue the discussion in chat. So as I tried to do this, the user did not have enough reps to continue in chat.

Is there any way around this? Or shall I go against the suggestion and continue to comment?

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543123/mysql-connect-function-not-having-the-right-username-password?noredirect=1#comment41710576_26543123)

Comment: You'll have to wait 'till they get enough rep to chat. It's not like they need to get a lot...

Comment: Sure, I understand. But if I continue to comment is that considered bad practice on here?

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, it seems like the issue's been resolved already.

Comment: There is a [feature request on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/168333) for the ability to invite low-rep users to a dedicated chat.

Comment: I think it's OK if it stays to just asking for clarification. The OP itself can update the question instead of commenting the additional information, the comments can then be removed. It the comments get too long it probably means that the question is not clear enough and the OP should edit it. Even though it's suggested there is no limit for how many comments a post can have, but the comments may be purged if they go off-topic.